# How to fix : Prefix "100" in front of all Anaconda packages

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

There is a prefix of "100" in front of all my python packages in anaconda navigator.  I believe this is making it difficult for applications to use these libraries.  For example, I cannot open Spyder.

Packages will be listed as "100 numpy" rather than simply "numpy"

I was in the middle of creating a virtual environment seperate from the root folder but I was doing a few install / uninstall of different packages using both Navigator and Anaconda Prompt.  Suddenly just about everything with my python installation started having problems. After closing Spyder I have not been able to reopen it. I tried spyder --reset which did not work.  I've tried several complete reinstalls of Anaconda and each time my root installation (as well as any other venvs I create) have a prefix of 100 in front of the package name.

I would expect the packages to read "numpy" rather than "100 numpy" etc.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well!

Answer (score 4):

I have also experienced this issue. For me, this occurred after running `conda update --all` in the anaconda terminal. I was able to fix this by rolling back my conda version to the version prior to my update that broke it.

To do this, go to anaconda prompt and type in `conda list --revisions` to find the revision number prior to whichever update broke anaconda. They you just type in `conda install --revision #`, replacing "#" with the revision number.

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, however, it didn't affect Spyder. It occured after I added the conda-forge channel. After updating all packages using `conda update --all`, all packages were updated from the conda-forge channel.

I fixed this by removing conda-forge from my environment's channels and updating all packages using above command, which actually 'downgrades' a lot of packages that were more recent in the conda-forge channel. You can do this, by using:

```
conda config --remove channels conda-forge
```

afterwards, do

```
conda update --all
```

If this is your problem and you want to keep conda-forge because the base channel doesn't include the desired package, appending it to your channel list should work, instead of giving it highest priority, by using

`conda config --append channels conda-forge`